# Extract two many-to-many's in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: country, news and a relationship table country_news. A country has many news and news can be from many countries. I want to do a look up from a country to extract all the relevant news, which is easy:

```
SELECT news.* FROM country, news, country_news
WHERE country.id = 1
  AND country_news.country_id = country.id
  AND country_news.news_id = news.id
```

But now I would like to extract the countries associated with the found news as well. I haven't tried a multiple select because I would like to avoid it when possible. I tried joins and group_concat, but I could not get it to work. Is this possible in one query?

Comment: Why the down vote? I don't think the answer is very straight forward, hence it is a good question.

Comment: Upvoted to compensate, I don't see this as a `downvote without giving a reason` kind of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT n.*, c2.* FROM country c
  JOIN country_news cn
    ON cn.country_id = c.id
  JOIN news n
    ON cn.news_id = n.id
  LEFT JOIN country_news cn2
    ON cn2.news_id = n.id
  LEFT JOIN country c2
    ON cn2.country_id = c2.id
WHERE c.id = 1
```

Comment: +1 Assuming the user wants all associated countries for news stories related to country 1, this looks like the only answer that would work (although `LEFT JOIN country f2` should be `LEFT JOIN country c2`).

Comment: Thank you very much, this one works like a charm! I don't think I would have found this query any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select country.id from country c right Join  
country_news cn on c.id=cn.country_id 
where  cn.news_id = @newsid
```

should give you all country ids for a specific newsid

Comment: This works as you say (if you change country.id to c.id), but I would like to have a query from a country, resulting in all the news with all the associated countries.

Answer (score 0):

You should just select country specific columns as well.

```
SELECT country.name as country_name, news.* FROM country, news, country_news WHERE country.id = 1 AND country_news.country_id = country.id AND country_news.news_id = news.id;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The news is extracted correct, but the associated countries are not.